# Prevent gather* from creating new line

Tags: math-mode, environments, amsmath, inline

I've been trying to use the gather* environment for non-aligned centered
equations within enumerate but I would like to prevent the new line that gather* inserts at the beginning of each item. Is there any easy way to
do this? I tried inline gathered but it does not center the equations
in the middle of the line like gather* does.

Comment: I don't really understand, if you don't want a line break, don't insert one. Can you show us a code example?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. the gather* and align* environments are display environments

Comment: Yes, I know. So you want `$\begin{gathered}a\\b\end{gathered}$`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes almost. Unfortunately this does not center the equations
at the center of each line. I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: You don't have an empty line before your `gather*` environment by any chance, do you?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Nope.  gather* starts at the next line of the item's label.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you, \hfill was what I've been missing.

Comment: Sorry about my previus, confused comments, I'm an idiot who can't read.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No worries, happens to everyone.